# WHILE Loop through a table to gain new column in a SELECT statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to loop through a table within a `CASE` statement ideally, but don't know if that is possible.

I have created a `CASE` statement and want to see which row agrees with which statement ( the statement is dependant on the table for values to meet the statement and gain a result in a new column).

Here is my attempt so far:

```
    Use Migration

    Declare @IMO_Number numeric(7,0)
    Declare @Asset_Type varchar(100) 

        Set @IMO_Number = 9126807
        Set @Asset_Type = 'vessel'

    Declare @tablevar table(ID INT IDENTITY, RADA_Groups nvarchar(100))
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('NOTATION INFORMATION')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('ASSET INFORMATION GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('ENGINE GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('TURBINE GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('SHAFTING AND GEARING GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('PROPULSOR AND THRUSTER GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('THERMAL TRANSFER EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('SHIP CONTROL EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('PRESSURE EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('PUMPING AND VALVE EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('BLOWER AND FAN GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('INERT GAS GENERATION GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('OIL PROCESSING EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('FILTRATION EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ( 'FRESH WATER GENERATING GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('ELECTRICAL EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('NAVIGATIONAL EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('ANCHORING, MOORING AND TETHERING GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('DECK GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('DECK STRUCTURES GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('SUPERSTRUCTURE AND DECKHOUSE GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('SHELL AND APPENDAGES GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('CARGO HOLD GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('CARGO EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('SPACES GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('TANK GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('RAMP AND DOOR GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('WASTE PROCESSING EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('ZONE GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('LIFTING APPLIANCE GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('JACKING EQUIPMENT GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('STATUTORY INFORMATION GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('SYSTEM GROUP')
    INSERT INTO @tablevar VALUES ('INCIDENT AND DEFECT GROUP')



    DECLARE @LoopCounter INT, @MaxId INT 
            , @group NVARCHAR(100)

    SELECT @LoopCounter = min(ID), @MaxId = max(ID)
    from @tablevar

    WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL and @LoopCounter <= @MaxId)
    BEGIN
       SELECT @group = RADA_Groups   
       FROM @tablevar WHERE ID = @LoopCounter

        SELECT Asset.LR_Asset_ID--,vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GGGGP, vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GGGP, vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GGP, 

    vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GP, vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.P, vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.I
            , Item.Item_Name, Item_Type.Item_Type_Name, Attri

    bute_Type.Attribute_Type_Name, Attribute.Attribute_Value, Attribute_LOV.Attribute_Value 

    --%% I am trying to loop all the table strings through every row of a select query and create a new column based on the WHEN 'statement'%%--

          , CASE

WHEN vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GGGGP = @group or vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GGGP= @group or vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GGP= @group or vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.GP= @group or vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.P= @group or vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.I= @group THEN @group 
            END as 'Group'

        FROM [dbo].Attribute
        JOIN [dbo].Item
        ON Attribute.Item_ID = Item.Item_ID
        JOIN [dbo].Item_Type
        ON Attribute.Item_Type_ID = Item_Type.Item_Type_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].Attribute_LOV
        ON Attribute.Attribute_LOV_ID = Attribute_LOV.Attribute_LOV_ID
        JOIN [dbo].Attribute_Type
        ON Attribute_Type.Attribute_Type_ID = Attribute.Attribute_Type_ID AND Attribute_Type.Item_Type_ID = Attribute.Item_Type_ID
        JOIN [dbo].Asset
        ON Attribute.Asset_ID = Asset.Asset_ID

        JOIN vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx
        ON vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.I = Item_Type.Item_Type_Name and vGetHierarchyTypeNameEx.asset_type_name = @Asset_Type

        WHERE Asset.LR_Asset_ID = @IMO_Number  and Attribute_Type.Description_Order IS NOT NULL and Attribute_Type.Attribute_Type_Name <> 'CHECKED'


        SELECT @LoopCounter  = min(ID) FROM @tablevar
        WHERE Id > @LoopCounter
    END
```

The results from this query are 34 separate select statements that are correct individually (e.g. the first statement identifies all rows that agree with being a 'Notation Information Group' and nothing else and the second select statement all rows that agree with being 'Asset information group' etc...), but if all of these queries could be combined it would be exactly what I am after.

I feel I am looping through the table at the wrong point or possibly need to find a way of combining all the results (possibly a UNION all)?

Comment: Could you provide a good sample for us - try to reduce number of tables/columns involved, and we probably don't need 34 samples from one table,but some sample rows for all (relevant) tables + expected results? Given we don't know your other tables (structure + data), I can't run this current query to see what it's actually producing. There's almost certainly a simpler solution that doesn't involve loops at all. But no real spec + no sample data + no expected results means I'm unable to help you at this point.

Comment: The only advice I can give you is please don't loop through rows like this! At least use a Fast_Forward cursor or even better! Stop thinking in rows and think in terms of sets. Many queries targeting the dataset union'd together or put the case statement in the select